# Error: Call to a member function update() on array laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am getting this error "Call to a member function  update() on array" and I have no idea why, is it because I am updating an array? I have check other resources similar to this but not much related to array so I am not sure what to do. Thank you in advance

Information: I am trying to update an HTML table but kept getting this error

Controller:

```
public function update1(Request $request, $id){
    $object2 = qualification::find($id);
    $object2 = array();
$object2['School'] = implode(' , ', $request->School);
$object2['SDate'] = implode(' , ', $request->SDate);
$object2['EDate'] = implode(' , ', $request->EDate);
$object2['qualification'] = implode(' , ', $request->qualification);
 $object2->update();
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

qualification model:

```
class qualification extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = array('School', 'user_id', 'SDate', 'EDate', 'qualification');

    // DEFINE RELATIONSHIPS --------------------------------------------------
    public function personal_infos() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\personal_info');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Update your model instead.

Comment: U mean change the things inside qualification model?

Comment: @fubar I have added my qualification model into my question, shouldn't the model be like this?

Comment: Yes, so what are you trying to accomplish with `$object2`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the attributes on your `Qualification` model either individually, or all at once and then call `save()`.

```
public function update1(Request $request, $id){
    $object2 = qualification::find($id);
    $test = array();
    $test['School'] = implode(' , ', $request->School);
    $test['SDate'] = implode(' , ', $request->SDate);
    $test['EDate'] = implode(' , ', $request->EDate);
    $test['qualification'] = implode(' , ', $request->qualification);
    $object2->update($test);
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do an update, not save but I managed to find out what you meant when you say update my model. Where I had to do this "$object2->update($test);" The $object2 variable from the array need to be changed to $test. Thanks a lot for your help !!

Comment: Calling `save()` on an existing model will update it. If it's a new model, it'll insert the data into the database.